# How to deploy simple JMS application on application server?

Tags: java, jms

I need help here with the below issue. I am learning JMS and I am quite new to it. I came across a tutorial which I was following, however when I try to run this by selecting the project in eclipse I do not get an option to run on server. Is there a way we can run a simple java application on application servers?

Below is the link to the tutorial I am following

https://www.javatpoint.com/jms-tutorial

I have mostly worked with dynamic web projects for which the option is present to run on server.

I have not posted the code as it's the exact same as given in the tutorial.

Comment: Did u create a server runtime? Also you could have a look at project facets if there is something deployable enabled, e.g. EJB Module if you want to pack the application as an EJB-jar.

Comment: Meini yes I have configuref glass fish server in eclipse as the runtime

Comment: also I will have to take a look at EJB modules, do not really have enough exposure to it.

Comment: If you are working / want to work with maven you could use maven-glassfish-plugin or maven-cargo-plugin

Comment: I am working with ant for now, however there is a plan to migrate to maven but thats not in the near future!

Answer (score 1):

For that you need to figure out which server(s) you want to deploy JMS. You can go with Weblogic or with ActiveMQ.

Below are the 2 reference links that would actually help you to resolve your query :

http://www.catgovind.com/java/test-weblogic-jms-java/

https://javainsider.wordpress.com/tag/jms-with-activemq-sample-example/

Comment: Anish Bhavnani I am using glassfish as given in the tutorial, will glassfish not support it?. I will also take a look at the link you have shared for weblogic but due to some organizational constraint I am bound to use glassfish for now to test it.

Comment: Ok, you can try below 2 links for working with glassfish server : 

https://hub.packtpub.com/setting-glassfish-jms-and-working-message-queues/
 
or
https://nnbharadwaj.wordpress.com/2012/10/02/simple-jms-example/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I would suggest you to go through spring-boot.

Here, you have an option to try a simple Hello World application 
http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/spring/your-first-jms-application-with-spring-boot

In the above example, you just have 2 java classes and one maven pom xml file to edit :)

Just try it out. 
You can configure it to run from your eclipse too.

In/with spring-boot -

- you don't have to do any web-server configuration on your own. Spring boot itself contains a web container.
- It just creates a JAR file with which you can just run your application as "as your run a jar" which has your code + server.

And my last point is - you will get lots of support from different forums as spring boot is used widely.

Comment: Thanks for the spring boot tip however again due to some organizational constraints I will not be able to use spring boot as of now till I conculde that its not possible to get the job done with a simple java application smilyface

Comment: It's ok. Thank you for the reply. But I would suggest you to try at least in your machine (official/personal) to get to know how easy to configure and to work with. Once you started working with spring boot you will love it, I am sure. Wish you Happy Xmas & New year !